# How to pass variables to a different buttons and save them in a csv file in xamarin forms?

Tags: file, csv, button, xamarin.forms, timestamp

can you help me?

I have a xamarin forms app that need to take a timestamp and time elapsed but i dont know how to obtain the value of a button to another and i would like to save in csv file.

I have the method to save the string into a file with the correct format but the file system will give me problems with storage directory  permissions

[my app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrYj3.png)

Here It's my code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace appRegistroAct
{

    public partial class PageRegistroActividades : ContentPage
    {
        string timeStampInicio = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        string timeStampFin = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //variables of the events

        public PageRegistroActividades (List<string> Param1, List<string> Param2)
        {

            InitializeComponent ();

           // visual studio doesn't recognize this variables
          //var timeStampInicio = DateTime.Now.ToString();
          //var timeStampFin = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            picker_actor1.Title = "Selecciona un Actor";
            picker_activity.Title = "Selecciona una acción";
            picker_actor2.Title = "Selecciona un Actor";

            picker_actor1.ItemsSource = Param1;
            picker_activity.ItemsSource = Param2;
            picker_actor2.ItemsSource = Param1;
        }


        private void Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            //unhandled exception
            this.timeStampInicio = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

       private void Btn_EventoFin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {
           //unhandled exception
           this.timeStampFin = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       }

       private void BtnSaveEvento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args, string timeStampInicio, string timeStampFin, string actor1, string actor2)
       {
             //I need to set the file path to a editable directory
            File.AppendAllText("read_file.csv", $"{actor1},{actor2},
            {timeStampInicio},{timeStampFin}\n");
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the variables timestamp of the class, it gives me an error, if I emulate my app with the variables commented, when I click the button "Guardar registro" the app stops and visual studio gives me Unhandled Exception: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 31:17. Method BtnSaveEvento_Clicked does not have the correct signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, there are several severe issues with your code. If this is a real project I'd recommend to you to sit down and get the basics right. If it's this is just an excercise you are writing to learn, then fine, proceed.

Obviously you are trying to use several concepts that you don't understand yet, and mash them into one great mess (no offense, though) - but I'll try do disentangle all of this and hopefully you'll learn something.

**Events and return values**

*(I tried to separate these, but the way they are tied here renders it impossible to.)*

In your code you are trying to use the return value of `Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked` from `Btn_EventoFin_Clicked` - this is not how it works. A event is very similar to a method. It is called at some time (with the difference, that the executed code may live at another place than the caller) and (if it has a return value - which is the case here) eventually returns its return value to the caller. Anyway, you can't simply call `Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked();` later in order to get the return value.

`Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked` is the *handler* for the `Button.Click` event, which is raised when the `Button` is clicked and in your case returns the timestamp as a `string`. If it was possible to call `Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked();` as you did (it is not, because the method signature does not match) , it would not return the time when the button was clicked, but the current time, since you are calling the method *again*.

Furthermore you can't simple make up what data should be passed to and returned from events. They have a defined signature, which is

```
void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
```

You can choose the names to your liking, but the types must match. There are some events with a more specialized `EventArgs` parameter, but `EventArgs` will always work. An event handler

```
private void BtnSaveEvento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args, string timeStamp1, string timeStamp2, string actor1, string actor2)
```

or

```
string Btn_EventoFin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

is simply not legal.

**The state of a class**

That code-behind thingy of `PageRegistroActividades` is a *class*. Basically spoken classes are structures that can hold data that is or is not accessible to the outside and methods that operate on this data. The way you are using it it's only methods and no data (at least no data that you define by yourself), which makes it hard to achieve what you want.

The timestamps are no data that belongs to the buttons, but rather belongs to your class. You *could* define fields in your class that can hold this data

```
class PageRegistroActividades : ContentPage /* or whatever */
{
    DateTime timeStampInicio;
    DateTime timeStampFin;

    private void Btn_EventoInicio_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.timeStampInicio = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private string Btn_EventoFin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.timeStampFin = DateTime.Now; //event end
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

**Writing to the file**

If you are using `File.AppendAllText` you don't have to open a file stream explicitly (it's done implicitly within the call to `AppendAllText`). You can simplify your code to

```
private void BtnSaveEvento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   File.AppendText(actor1 + ","); /* Have to create member variables for these, too */
   File.AppendText(actor2 + ","); 
   File.AppendText(timeStampInicio + ","); 
   File.AppendText(timeStampFin + ","); 
   File.AppendText("\n");
}
```

You are calling `AppendAllText` multiply, which is unecessary and a waste of resoources. It's easier to use string interpolation

```
File.AppendAllText($"{actor1},{actor2},{timeStampInicio},{timeStampFin}\n");
```

or `String.Format`

```
File.AppendAllText(string.Format({0},{1},{2},{3}\n", actor1, actor2, timeStampInicio, timeStampFin);
```

**Remarks:** Using a `Stream` can be beneficial if you have to write to a file more than once, but to write to the file, you would need a `StreamWriter` instead of a `StreamReader`. You can define the `StreamWriter` on the class level, but you have to make sure to dispose it (read on it).

**The loop**

An upper bound of `1` for a `for`-loop that starts at zero does not really make sense. The code within the loop will execute exactly once, hence you can replace the loop by the statements within it.

Comment: thanks for the info, i didn't know about file append this method is ery useful.

Comment: thanks for the info, i didn't know about file append method and is very useful.  About this operator, if I include it in my functions and create variables in my class. method BtnSaveEvento_Clicked does not have the correct signature